# is it possible to run Visual-studio 2008 on mini laptop?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

is it possible to run Visual-studio 2008 on mini laptop ?

procesor: Intel ® Atom N270 1.6GHz

memory: 1GB DDR2

HD: 160GB SATA

thank's in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows xp sp2 and above should be able to handle that.

I have similar specs laptop (acer aspireone, 1.6Atom, 1GB, 1024x600, XP SP3), I have visual studio 2008 express and running fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have a netbook with the exact same specs and it does run vs2008.

It's not extremely fast but I can use it to test code snippets away from my desktop PC.

If you have a faster machine I suggest you also setup vs2008 on it so you can Remote Desktop from the netbook and perform long builds or other CPU intensive tasks.

Answer (score 0):

It may *well* be possible. Whether it's advisable, I have my doubts. You should choose the gruntiest machine, with a decent screen size, that you can afford for development since it will more than pay for itself in increased productivity and reduced development time.

The minimum requirements are:

- 1.6 GHz CPU, 384 MB RAM, 1024x768 display, 5400 RPM hard drive

Recommended:

- 2.2 GHZ or higher CPU, 1024 MB or more RAM, 1280x1024 display, 7200 RPM or higher hard drive, 1.22 GB of available disk space for the minimum installation, 2 GB of available disk space for the full installation

And minimum requirements are notorious for being publisged by the marketing department rather than the techs, so take taht with a grain of salt. Your machine *barely* meets those so I would suggest you should be looking for a better machine.

Answer (score 0):

From the [VS Readme](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/a/e/9ae0f6cc-7032-408e-9ca7-989f9e4af4ec/VS2008Readme.htm)

1.1. Supported Architectures

- x86
- x64 (WOW)

1.2. Supported Operating Systems

- Windows XP Service Pack 2 or above
- Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1 or above
- Windows Server 2003 R2 or above
- Windows Vista
- Windows Server 2008

1.3. Hardware Requirements

- Minimum: 1.6 GHz CPU, 384 MB RAM, 1024x768 display, 5400 RPM hard disk
- Recommended: 2.2 GHz or higher CPU, 1024 MB or more RAM, 1280x1024 display, 7200 RPM or higher hard disk
- On Windows Vista: 2.4 GHz CPU, 768 MB RAM

So it will probably run. It may not be usable WRT screen real estate and it would run better with more RAM, but it should run.

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft:
Minimum: 1.6 GHz CPU, 384 MB RAM, 1024x768 display, 5400 RPM hard disk
Recommended: 2.2 GHz or higher CPU, 1024 MB or more RAM, 1280x1024 display, 7200 RPM or higher hard disk

I know that Visual Studio 2008 runs fairly slowly on a 2.4GHz laptop with 1GB RAM, so I can't imagine that it would run all that well on a 1.6GHz machine.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=D95598D7-AA6E-4F24-82E3-81570C5384CB&displaylang=en), i guess no. As the screen is too small (min. 1024x768) and cpu power is not enough. (1.6G traditionally means P4...atom should be slower)

Answer (score 0):

it should but don't expect it to be super fast or anything.

[blog link](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/05/14/my-hp-mini-runs-visual-studio-2010.aspx)

[other related so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947500/would-you-run-visual-studio-and-windows-7-on-a-dell-mini-netbook)

[server fault link](https://serverfault.com/questions/12914/netbook-vs-notebook-for-programmers)